# Flask application not rendering html page despite no errors

Tags: python, html, flask

Just getting a white blank screen without errors.I've tried it out in Pycharm and there is no problem there, only in VS Code

The Flask app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
        return render_template('index.html')


app.run(
        port=5000,
        debug=True
)
```

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to access my page with this adress: http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Here is how it looks like in the browser:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/to4X9.png

Comment: can you add a  `print('something')` before `return render_template('index.html')`? Can you see the print?

Comment: Good idea, it seems it's not showing the print.

Comment: This can explain something ... :-)

Comment: Yes, but i checked the syntax multiple times and have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: How do you run Flask? Maybe you have few copies running? Try to look around..

Comment: And I woudl assume, that it does enter to the index function because is detects the html file.

Comment: Now i can see the print inside the function, but still no content on the page

Comment: What didi you do in order to see the print?

Comment: Closed all python apps in task manager

Comment: And also, if i write return "string" instead of render template, i can always see that in the browser

Comment: are you using `flask run` or `python app.py`?

Comment: Are you using linux? can you please check for:
- other python running processes
- other processes using port 5000
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding this? Or are you using another file to run your application?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(
      port=5000,
      debug=True)
```